# How to stop SQL replies to commands in Python Shell

Tags: python, mysql, web.py

I've Googled this question in a dozen different ways and can find no joy.  I think I'm asking the wrong question or using the wrong words.

I'm making MySQL entries and queries from a Python script on my Linux server in a WEBPY framework.  Everything works great is the good news.  The bad news is that I'm filling up a log with responses from MySQL:

```
>>import web
>>db = web.database(dbn='mysql', user='myuser_name', pw='MyPassword', db='My_database')
>>lookup = db.query("SELECT track FROM playlist ORDER BY timestamp ASC")
#0.0 (1): SELECT track FROM playlist ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

To stop the response SQL gave me, am I looking for a configuration in MySQL, WEBPY or the setting when I open the db?

Any and all advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `db.printing = False`